# Theoretical Hashing Question

Tags: hash

I am testing a theoretical hash function, $f()$, which produces n-bits of output.

By the pigeon hole principle, if I run $f(x)$ over a search space of $1+2^n$ values, I will get at least one collision. According to the birthday problem I should get many more collisions than that.

Is there a similar principle that I can determine how many values of $x$ will be needed to ensure with high probability  that I have produced all possible $2^n$ values of $f(x)$?

I'm relatively certain that there is no 100% guarantee of obtaining all values, but at least an approximation within a degree of confidence should be possible. Are these approximations only practical when considering specific hashing algorithms?

Comment: Belongs on Crypto SE?

Comment: Uhm, why are you testing a theoretical hash function? Are you a security researcher? If not, it might be prudent to stick to existing hash functions.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107081/does-every-hash-value-have-an-inverse-value

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Tail_estimates ​ ​

Answer (score 6):

If $f()$ can be modeled as a random function (that is, if each output for a distinct input is independent of all other outputs), then this is a well studied problem in probability theory, known as the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).

The link I gave you gives more details; the bottom line is that you start getting good probability of seeing all possible sequences after around $C n 2^n$, for a constant $C$ not too far from 1 (and whose actual value depends on what "good probability" actually is).

Of course, if your theoretical hash function doesn't act randomly (for example, there are pairs of inputs $A \ne B$ where we're guarranteed that $f(A) \ne f(B)$), this analysis does not apply.

Comment: Isn't it $\Theta(n\log(n))$-time since this is expected?

Comment: @kelalaka: when I wrote $Cn2^n$, $n$ is the number of bits (just as micker used it).  $\theta(n \log n)$ is what you get when $n$ is the size of the sample space (and so there are $\log_2 n$ bits...)

Comment: @kelalaka: he specifies that $n$ is the number of bits within the output of $f$; hence using that same notation in the answer makes sense (rather than changing the meaning of $n$)